# Canvas sin curve much blurred. i dont know why its blurred

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, canvas

I draw a sine curve in html5 canvas. but the curve was much blurred. pls help me to resolve.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5hL9bbk1/)

```
  var Wave=[];
        for(i=0;i<6.28;i+=0.03)
                {
            Wave.push([(i*(350/6.28)),130-(Math.sin(i)*80)]);
                }   
      ctx.beginPath();                  
      ctx.moveTo(50+Wave[0][0],Wave[0][1])
      for(i=0;i<Wave.length;i++)
                {
                ctx.lineTo(50+Wave[i][0],Wave[i][1]);
                ctx.strokeStyle="red";
                ctx.lineWidth=1.5;
                ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
                ctx.stroke();
                }
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/umaar/fWSUk/

Comment: @InvernoMuto i already seen this. the same logic. i used but i cant figure out why this line was blurry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are adding a new line segment in each iteration of the second `for` loop but you are also drawing the stroke for all previous segments, which results in the segments to be drawn multiple times. Call `ctx.stroke()` only once, after the loop.

```js
function DrawCurve() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
 
  var Wave = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 6.28; i += 0.03) {
    Wave.push([(i * (350 / 6.28)), 130 - (Math.sin(i) * 80)]);
  }

  ctx.beginPath();     
  ctx.moveTo(50 + Wave[0][0], Wave[0][1]);

  for (var i = 0; i < Wave.length; i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(50 + Wave[i][0], Wave[i][1]);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
    ctx.lineWidth = 1.5;
    ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
  }

  ctx.stroke();
}

DrawCurve();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="430" height="260"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dear. simple matter. i cant figure out.

Comment: @Neophyte bit rude. the `ctx.stroke();` is now outside of the for loop and only called once.

Comment: also @chrisklaussner you dont need to set the `stokeStyle`, `lineWidth` and `lineJoin` in the loop as this only needs to be set once and are read when `ctx.stroke()` is called!

Comment: @rorypicko You're right. It was just a copy-paste from Neophyte's original Fiddle, though. :)